# Can Redis persistence (rdb) be sent directly to a GCP bucket?

Tags: redis

Just modified the redis.conf file but I'm unable to make it work. Everything is (supposed) to be set correctly (ports open, etc).

I just need to be sure there is no restriction on Redis-GCP data flow by design.

thanks.